# Styling tooltips on a button

Tags: button, styling

I wanted to learn how to make a tooltip on a button, and I saw that you can just do it with title, but can you also move the location of the tooltip? And style what it looks like? Is it the same method as CSS? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the simplest method to use tooltips is [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="My tooltip">Check me</a>
```

More examples you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp) and [here (bootstrap v4)](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/).

Comment: Thanks Ill check it out. I bootstrap hard to learn? I have no experience with it

Comment: In my opinion it's very clear and easy to use. In many cases it is like "find example and modify it". It is well documented too.

Comment: Awesome. I think I can figure it out. Thanks again